# Is the android app cache cleared after app force close by os?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

im building an android app and i need to save some files locally on the SD card. The question i want to ask is that does the android OS clear the app cache

```
mnt/sdcard/Android/data/app_name/cache/*
```

get cleared after the app is closed by the os due to lack of memory ( sigkill sent) ? 
In what conditions or when is the cache cleared. If the app needs to save some file safely where should it store them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> get cleared after the app is closed by the os due to lack of memory ( sigkill sent) ?

It should not be cleared in that case.

> In what conditions or when is the cache cleared.

Definitely when the user elects to clear it, or when the app is uninstalled. The external cache directory is not automatically cleared due to low storage conditions.

---

> If the app needs to save some file safely where should it store them?

That depends on your definition of "safely".

Comment: by "safely" i  mean the file being there until deleted by some user action.

Comment: @ghostCoder: Nothing on external storage is "safe". Not only can any other application go in and delete files, but on Android 1.x and 2.x devices, external storage may not be available. From the standpoint of "being there until deleted by some user action", you need to use `getFilesDir()` to get at your application's portion of internal storage.

Comment: is there any way to avoid app kill when clearing app data pragmatically

Answer (score 1):

- FC doesn't clear your cache. FC means that your app's process is killed. So it doesn't affect the cache
- your app's cache is cleared when you manually select clear data and clear cache under Managing Applications in Settings
- For a safe storage, use your external storage. External storage is usually much bigger than the internal storage. (Here safe means, avoid frequently running out of space as compared to internal storage)

Comment: What evidence do you have that the external cache directory is erased when a process is killed? The documentation does not mention that.

Comment: thanks for pointing out. it was a bad sentence which is fixed :)