# If we save cache data in application directory instead of cache directory can we prevent data purging when phone is on low memory or software upgrade

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

The data stored in the cache directory is getting deleted when phone is on low memory. if we cache the data in application's internal storage directory where user data is stored can this be avoided.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8895413/9473786) - I don't think cache is cleared unless the user requests it. The app can certainly be stopped and things like static cars lost, but that's not the same as cache data.

Comment: And since the question is marked as both Android and iOS, I can add that in iOS it's similar. In a nutshell, contents of the folders other than the cache are removed only manually by you, or by removing the app.